# Mean separation when interaction is significant

Tags: anova, interaction, inference

I am analyzing  a factorial experiment in RCBD (3 cultivars x 4 inoculation methods with 10 replicates). All main effects and interactions are significant for a particular response variable. But in SAS (I am using SAS 9.4) mean separation is possible only for the main effects but not for the interaction means. When the interaction is significant I think we can not make any conclusions about the main effects. May I ask someone to help me how to go ahead with this please. Thanks much for your time to answer this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in that you cannot make any conclusions about the main effects when there is an interaction. I believe it is valid to analyze the groups for which you found interactions separately, however, I would suggest to double check and confirm this.

There is a function (test.Interactions) in the package phia (in R) that you can use to analyze the interactions and main effects, though.